# JQuery AJAX success + fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fadein

I'm using AJAX to load survey content into a container on a page, and during the transition, I fadeOut the container and fadeIn when it's done. It works fine for pages 1-4, but stops working for page 5. The content loads for page 5, but the container doesn't fadeIn.

```
success: function(data){
    $("div#surveyContainer").fadeOut(function(){
        $("div#surveyContainer").html(data).hide().fadeIn();
    }); // end fadeout
}
```

There is no reference to `surveyContainer` anywhere in page 5. All I can think of is that something is timing out causing the `fadeIn` to not get triggered. The load time is about 36ms. I set the php script to where it's sending `data` to report all errors (and the data is making it into the Db just fine), but all I'm getting is the content I expect, but the container stays `display:none`. If I remove the fades, everything works fine :/

I've also tried this to no avail:

```
success: function(data){
    $("div#surveyContainer").fadeOut(function(){
        $("div#surveyContainer").html(data);
        $("div#surveyContainer").fadeIn();
    }); // end fadeout
}
```

Comment: Post the HTML that is being sent back from the server.

Comment: Why are you hiding the div again ? You already hid it with `fadeOut`

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: because if i don't, it doesn't work at all. I would post the HTML, but it's like 2000 lines.

Comment: Have you tried sending back really simple HTML maybe just a `<div>test</div>` ? Just to make sure the html is not invalid ?

Comment: are you getting anything at all in the console window? `F12`

Comment: Damn. It's the something in page 5. when I did `<div>test</div>` it worked. I don't get any errors in Dreamweaver tho…

Comment: also i haven't changed anything in page 5 in like a week and it was working this morning

Comment: without showing us page 5, we can't really help any further. perhaps post your javascript used in page 5?.. make a JSFiddle with your html and JS and post the link to this question.

Comment: Actually it turned out it was none of these things: this happens over a secure connection and when I updated jQuery (I needed .prop() which is new in v1.6) I linked to jquery.com/jquery-latest.js. I hosted the file locally and everything works fine >:O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't link to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js from a page using encryption (HTTPS). Host the code locally.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `.stop();` [see reference here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/stop/&ei=bU7eTp2PMaGT0QHtg5TJBw&usg=AFQjCNFCD2RXaw6OiM6D_DNnRohDGZLRGw&sig2=nX4KEYQv_Pxrw-hWIqkc5Q)

```
success: function(data){
    $("div#surveyContainer").fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).html(data).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    }); // end fadeout
}
```

This should stop any animations that are currently happening, force them to go straight to their ending point (where they were animating to) and clear the animation queue. You can probably get rid of the `hide()` this way too.

Also, you can just use `this` inside the callback for, well, I dont' know why. but you can.

Comment: But the data is getting populated after the `fadeOut` has finished, so theoretically there shouldn't be a need for `stop`.

Comment: Hence beginning my answer with 'try' :)  Without seeing the code and being able to test it, this is my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it would break on a individual page tho.

Perhaps you could try it in the callback of `.hide()`:

```
$("div#surveyContainer").html(data).hide('slow', function(){
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

**As Interstellar_Coder pointed out.** You have already hidden the `div#surveyContainer` when you faded it out. You now just need to load up your data and fade it in.

```
success: function(data){
    $("div#surveyContainer").fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).html(data).fadeIn(); // Removed the .hide()
    }); // end fadeout
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to hide it AFTER the data has been populated then re-show it ? You would want to hide the div before then show it after it's populated.

Comment: Thats what i did in the second example of chaining it better. I just copied his example to example the hide callback.

Comment: edited my answer to note the silly mistake, as pointed out by @Interstellar_Coder

Comment: That didn't work either :/ I also tried doing what i just added to the main question.